# how to create layer in html view (or increase z index of layer )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, ionic-framework

could you please tell me why my menu option come below the scrolling view ?

Actually I have one menu button on my screen when I open menu option on click of menu button .It show menu option and scroll my contend my scroll contend display above the menu option

[image]
http://plnkr.co/edit/G8mp53rQlF562hEkgmgT?p=preview

Menu option should come above the scrolling contend  ? I already increase z index..But not work ?

```
    .nav_bar {
    background: #597A4D!important;
    border-style: none;
    height: 44px;
    border: 0px!important;
    border-radius: 0px!important;
    z-index:99999;

}
```

Got The solution my own

**Anwser plunker**

```
.nav_bar {
    background: #597A4D!important;
    border-style: none;
    height: 44px;
    border: 0px!important;
    border-radius: 0px!important;
    z-index:99999;

}
```

Comment: where/how have you increased the z-index?

Comment: i used Z-index:99999; in menu option  but it not work.I try to add in this class navbar-collapse collapse in

Comment: for a start, Z-index != z-index, and "in menu option" means nothing. Show the CSS

Comment: i did not get what you are trying to say ? could you use plunker

Comment: You have CSS, add it to your question - I don't think you're doing it right

Comment: I read the question and looked at the plunkr but i really have no idea what the question is

Comment: and now you've removed the HTML - is it your goal to provide not enough information to answer the question, if so, mission completed - the plunker link isn't showing the issue - so - good luck, but I'm out

Comment: @element11 I will explain more ..ActuallY I have scrolling contend in my view .you can check after scroll the contend.but when I open my menu option on click of menu bar .it is showing menu options as shown in image ("home",about us" ...so on) now if you are scrolling the text my scrolling view display above the contend

Comment: @Shruti isn't your fixed code the same as the nonworking code?

Comment: No I got the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

The menu bar appears behind the scrolling container because both the containers are at the same stack order. Specifying z-index will give menu elements greater stack order.

Add z-index to list item.

```
.nav>li
{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

What Samir is trying to say is very simple, z-index implies the priority of how elements will be displayed in your browser. which means, if you apply

```
.nav->li
{
   z-index: 1;
}
```

the element will have the higher priority then the other elements. By defining z-index you are defining priority for your element's display, this way, avoiding situations as described in the question above.

there is no limit that I know of for defining z-index.